# Cygwin: How can I obtain the PID of a program started by CygStart?

Tags: bash, process, cygwin, pid

If I open a **CygWin Bash shell** and do:

```
Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal
$ notepad &
[1] 1880

Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal
$ echo $!
1880
```

the **PID variable** `$!` is correct.
But if I do:

```
Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal
$ cygstart notepad

Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal
$ echo $!
[No results]
```

This time `$!`has no value at all.

How can I **get the PID** of the **just started CygStart** program?

Comment: So what happens if you do `cygstart notepad &` And then `echo $!`

Comment: Then the PID is correctly assigned to `$!`, @BroSlow. Maybe this is the only way to make it.

Comment: @BroSlow, according to the answer of @AdrianFrühwirth, the `&` background method just gives back the PID of the cygstart process, not the notepad one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You *can* get the PID of the `cygstart` process via

```
$ cygstart notepad &
$ echo "$!"
```

but this won't do you any good since I guess you want to have control over the `notepad` process. Since `cygstart` starts `notepad` via Windows' [`ShellExecuteW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and because it consequently won't be a child process of `cygstart`/your current shell there is no way for you to `kill` it by `kill`ing `cygstart`.

You can easily verify this with [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: You are right, @AdrianFrühwirth , I would like, for example, to kill `notepad`. Maybe there is some way for Windows to report this PID somewhere. I think this will requiere the creation of a new question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez I know nothing about the Windows API but I guess the `ShellExecute*` functions are able to return a PID and that you can write your own wrapper/customize `cygstart` to print the PID to `stdout` so you can work with it in your script if this is really needed, just as additional hint.